# send clicks to "generated source/computed html" buttons via Chrome Dev Tools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

I have to review a large number of videos on a webpage (screenshot below). The videos are partially hidden. And to view each video, I have to click the `more` button one by one (as shown in the image below).
[image]

There are often 40 videos per page. Constantly scrolling and clicking the `more` button over and over again is tedious, and if I keep doing it I think I'll have a repetitive stress injury.

So, I thought I'd use Chrome Dev Tools' `console` to identify the buttons and send them clicks all in one batch process.

I am able to find the `more` buttons using the `inspect` tool in Chrome Dev Tools, like so:
[image]

The `more` button's DOM-tree breadcrumb via `inspect` (please CLICK to enlarge, there are two image parts below):

[image]

[image]

The `more` button markup code looks like this:

```
<button class="d2l-label-text" type="button">
    <d2l-icon class="d2l-button-subtle-icon" icon="d2l-tier1:chevron-down" dir="ltr"></d2l-icon>
    <span class="d2l-button-subtle-content"><!---->more<!----></span>
    <slot></slot>
</button>
```

and the `more` button's `class` is `d2l-label-text`

I thought I'd do something like this in the `console`:

```
> let allbuttonsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("d2l-label-text");

  for (let eachbutton of allbuttonsArray) {
    eachbutton.click();
  }
```

However, it turns out that `document.getElementsByClassName("d2l-label-text")` is not grabbing anything. The length of the result array is `0`.

I tried to play around with some other selectors and discovered that the `console` is not grabbing from the `generated source/computed html`, it's only grabbing tags/elements that are there in the `source` (the original source that can be obtained via `right-click, view source`).

**My Question:** What am I doing wrong? How do I get the `console` to grab the `generated source/computed html` `more` buttons?

Comment: Do you have a link to the page in question, or can you put together a sandbox that replicates the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen on the screenshots, the element is inside a [ShadowRoot](https://devdocs.io/dom/shadowroot) which means it's not accessible directly from the main `document`.

To find such an element you'll have to access the ShadowRoot chain recursively.
In your case there are two elements in this chain.

```
for (const more of document.querySelectorAll('d2l-more-less')) {
  for (const buttonSubtle of more.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('d2l-button-subtle')) {
    const btn = buttonSubtle.shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
    if (btn) btn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));
  }
}
```

In case the shadowRoot is created by the page in `'closed'` mode you'll probably have to hook `Element.prototype.attachShadow` in [page context script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried your code directly in the console and it didn't work. So I'm going to try the `Element.prototype.attachShadow` suggestion a little later. In particular, thank you for documenting your response so beautifully (with links). I've upvoted you and if the `attachShadow` suggestion works, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Start by verifying the state of ShadowRoot in devtools: https://puu.sh/EpwpX/1dc0c5de86.png

Comment: Thanks. Both the `shadow roots` are open, screencap here: https://imgur.com/qL0xbP1

Comment: Well it means the approach in this answer will work but you need to adapt it properly. For example those weren't classes, but element tag names, which I only now realized from your new screencap. Also maybe the element uses a different event listener like `mousedown`, which you can see in devtools "Event listeners" sub-panel. Anyway, I don't see how I can help further without trying the page myself.

Comment: Thanks brother: this is the final code that worked: `for (const more of document.querySelectorAll('d2l-more-less')) { for (const buttonSubtle of more.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('d2l-button-subtle')) { buttonSubtle.shadowRoot.querySelector('.d2l-label-text').click(); } }` (if you have any thoughts on why `btn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));}` didn't work, do share)

Comment: It's because the event listener is attached to `.d2l-label-text`, not to `button`, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the content you are trying to get is inside an iframe within the page?

If so I believe you'd need to get the iframe first then use

```
theiframe.getElementsByClassName()
```

Comment: The content is not in an `iframe`. Thank you for your useful suggestion. I saw some references to how `iframe` can be a cause of such behavior.

Comment: @thanks_in_advance then I think it would help to see more of the html.  A very basic test works. 

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
    </table>
    <script>
       table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

       table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));

     </script>

  </body>
</html>

---then in console---
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
console.log(rows.length);

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, Pineapple. Your basic test works for me (I put that code in a new `.htm` file and ran that code and it worked. I've added the HTML DOM-tree's breadcrumbs to my original question, please have a look (they're in a couple screenshots).